# load js on image click titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

i am new to titanium apps, i want to load a js on image click but i get 'uncaught typeerror cannot call method 'open' of undefined' error.

app.js

```
Ti.include("/core/index.js");
```

index.js

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
title: 'MapApp',
layout: 'vertical',
backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
});

var home=Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image:'home.png',
  height : 130,
  width : 130,  
});
var about=Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image:'about.png',
  height : 130,
  width : 130
});
var rss=Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image:'rss.png',
  height : 130,
  width : 130
});
var contact=Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image:'contact.png',
  height : 130,
  width : 130
});

home.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

var newWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
url : 'map.js',
title : 'title',
tabBarHidden : true,
barColor : '#000000',                
    });
    newWin.open({
animation:true
});  
});

win.add(home);
win.add(about);
win.add(rss);
win.add(contact);
win.open();
```

map.js

```
var globals = require("globals");

(function(){
    var config = require("Config"),
        AppWindow, LocationManager, locationsHandler;

    globals.theme = require("../themes/" + config.theme);
    LocationManager = require("LocationManager");

    Titanium.UI.backgroundColor = globals.theme.Global.backgroundColor;

    locationsHandler = function(e){
        AppWindow = require("../ui/AppWindow").create();
        AppWindow.open();
        Ti.App.removeEventListener(
            LocationManager.events.LOCATIONS_READY,
            locationsHandler
        );
    };

    Ti.App.addEventListener(
        LocationManager.events.LOCATIONS_READY,
        locationsHandler
    );

    // Load locations
    LocationManager.load(); 
})();
```

i searched a lot, but did  not get any response, is there any problem with the code in map.js as i replaced that code from app.js from purchased theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Event fire and event listener for this purpose and in my sense it will be the wise thing to do also. Once you have registered an even, fire it when the image is clicked. When the event is fired, the event you registered will hear it and will load your concern js and then you can take it from there.

[Here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Event_Handling) is the link that might help you to get it going. You may fire and register both the event in app.'s or in any other js you are using. 
Once you get it right, the other thing will be easy to do.

Comment: @RajeshVishnani the link that i have shared has the code snippet, take a look if something bother you there, we are here

Comment: i get error at var `globals = require("/core/globals");`, it says required document not found. where do i have to include this? in the app.js or map.js? infact i get error at every `require();` statement.

Comment: i edited the question according to your suggestion, can you please have a look? i am really tired of this problem

Comment: It works like this, you have some js file that you want to include in the the project you can put that file inside "lib" folder. If folder is not there, create it inside the "app" folder. From your problem what i can conclude is that you are having serious trouble in getting the structure right. Go through this link [link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Global-method-require). Share your full project somewhere and then we can look